# so, i think this is basic, but i need to know

Tags: java, stack

so, for an assignment, I have to do this part, but the if parts are red and i don't understand why

```
if (int >=1 && int<=7){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String direction;
    System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
    direction=sc.nextD();
    if (direction = 'left'){
        maze.push('left');
        System.out.println("Pushed left to stack");
```

I realize I forgot part of it.
updated code:

```
Stack maze = new Stack();
for(int x=1; x<=10; x++)
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    int a = ran.nextInt(10) + 1;
    if (int a>=1 && int a<=7){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String direction;
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        direction=sc.nextLine();
        if (direction.equals ("left") || direction.equals ("Left")){
            maze.push("left");
```

the if (int a>=1 && int a<=7) part doesn't work. everything else is fine

Comment: That's the compiler telling you that something is wrong with your code.  I'm not a compiler, but off the top of my head `'left'` is not a `String`, in Java strings are denoted with double quotes: `"left"`.

Comment: Also, `if (direction = "left")` is assignment, not comparison.  Also, also, `if (direction == "left")` is comparing reference equality and will also fail. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Replace `if (int a>=1 && int a<=7){` with `if (a >= 1 && a <=7) {`   `int a` will try to declare a new integer called a.

Comment: thanks. it works now

Comment: Great! Just a tip for the future: when writing code, make sure to fix the errors as they come up, instead of at the end. This will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So, here are some issues that I see:

1. `int` is not a variable; it is the name of a primitive type. You cannot name any variable as `int` in java, and you certainly can't do comparisons to it.
2. Scanner does not have a class called nextD(). You're probably looking for nextLine
3. In Java, strings are enclosed in double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`. In addition, to compare strings you need to use direction.equals("string"). See azurefrog's comment.

I'm assuming you're using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ (if you're not, you probably should). Hover over the red parts with your mouse and it should tell you what its complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

there is a variable `a` of type `int` do it like `if(a >=1 && a <=7)`

Answer (score -2):

Here is the correction for your code :-

```
int i=0;
int b=0;
if (i>=1 && b<=7){ /*you need to have variables for your int and u must 
define them before the if statment*/ 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String direction;
System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
direction=sc.next(); /*no D for Strings and .nextLine() if its separated by 
spaces*/.
if (direction.equals("left")) { /*String uses .equals() method inside for  
comparing equal strings*/.
    maze.push("left"); //String uses literals " "
    System.out.println("Pushed left to stack");
}}
```

Comment: In this case, the variables should not be declared in the if statement. Also, you're missing a closing paren in `if (direction.equals("left")`

Comment: It won't compile.

Comment: It will also never go past the first if statement, since i will always be 0.

Comment: It's also very difficult to read because you didn't explain your answer but crammed a bunch of comments in a code snippet (which is also missing indentation).

Comment: :) I just showed the guy his problems the code doesn't have to compile since I don't have his push method .